# How to get the floor (round down instead of up) of a number with AMPscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, math

I'm doing a bit of math with AMPscript, and I'd like to be able to round a number DOWN

eg: I would like `5.5`, `5.6`, `5.7` etc.. to become **`5`**, not `6`

The standard [**FormatNumber()**](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/math/FormatNumber.html) function will automatically round a number UP if the decimal point is greater than or equal to .5

I've tried finding a `Floor()` function or some option to `FormatNumber()` that will yield the rounded-down number, but I haven't had any luck finding a solution.

Does anyone have a suggestion for obtaining the floor value of a number?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can still use FormatNumber-- just subtract 0.5 from the number before feeding it into FormatNumber. Something like this would probably work:

```
FormatNumber(@OriginalNumber-0.5, "N0", "en-US")
```

Since you subtract 0.5, a number such as 1.99 becomes 1.49 which would round down, while 2.49 would become 1.99 and round up.

Comment: Simple and elegant.

Comment: Impressive.  The force is strong with this one!

Comment: this works: Set @rounded = FormatNumber(Subtract(@OriginalNumber,.5), "N0", "en-US")

Comment: @Snowalker's answer is correct.  You have to use the subtract function in AMPscript.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are ok, but I would like to add mine as it still uses FormatNumber and also supports negative numbers.

```
%%[ 
set @number = '4.500000001'
set @mod = Mod(@number, 1)

if @mod > .5 then 
    set @roundedDown = FormatNumber(Subtract(@number,1), 0)
elseif @mod < 0 AND @mod > -.5 then // handle negative values
    set @roundedDown = FormatNumber(Subtract(@number,1), 0)
else
    set @roundedDown = FormatNumber(@number, 0)
endif
]%%

Original Value: %%=v(@number)=%%
<br />
Rounded Down: %%=v(@roundedDown)=%%
```

Answer (score 3):

Another thought.  You could use server side javascript instead of AMPscript, and just use math.floor.

Comment: This will certainly work in other scenarios, but my situation involves sending content in an email (through ExactTarget), so the javascript won't execute

Comment: @ampersandre - Server Side Javascript is available to you in email sending. See http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/ for more info. Use of SSJS in email sends is extremely useful, however, more in-depth data retrieval can slow down sending. MATH.floor would not cause any harm here.

Answer (score 1):

This may seem a little hack-ish, but I would do it like this.

```
%%[ 
SET @DynamicField1 = 127.35
SET @DynamicField2 = Substring(@DynamicField1, 1,  Subtract(IndexOf(@DynamicField1, "."), 1) )
]%%
```

@DynamicField2 now is the floor.  Good luck

Comment: I changed 127.35 to 127.51 and it results into 127 instead of 128