# Format and multiply a number without rounding

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, formula-field, rounding, format

So I have

```
%%=FormatCurrency( Multiply(@365,339.00,1.5),"en-US",0,"$" )=%%
```

Which returns

```
$548,009
```

The issue with this is that it's rounded the .50 so it now ends in 9 not 8.

I've been working on this for a while and can't figure out a way.

I can't show any decimal places and I can't have the figure rounded either.

If anyone has any ideas that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Luke

Comment: You can refer to `setScale(scale)` or `setScale(scale, roundingMode)` methods. Please follow below link for more methods : [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm) . Something like this `oli.TotalPrice = (((parentListPrice * svcPercent) * discount) * oli.Quantity).setScale(2);`

Comment: @tandonprateek this is a marketing-cloud question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the floor (round down instead of up) of a number with AMPscript?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57646/how-to-get-the-floor-round-down-instead-of-up-of-a-number-with-ampscript)

Comment: Thanks guys

Yer it's kind of a duplicate however the main difference is that I've also got a multipication function in there so I couldn't apply that fix into my string.

I.E adding the -0.5 after @OriginalNumber like below @FormatNumber(@OriginalNumber-0.5, "N0", "en-US")

I'll try out the setScale method today.

Answer (score 0):

I Looked over your original code and it looks like you used the multiply function with 3 arguments which are 365, 339.00 and 1.5. I checked the SalesForce  Developer Documentation and it states the multiply function is too only accept two arguments. We can make this work if we utilize two variables for calculations and then create a 3rd variable to format the output.

I provided some sample code with an explanation on how we can make this work:

**VAR_1:** Multiplies the first two numbers together which are 365 & 339.00
**VAR_2:** Takes the output of VAR_1 and then multiplies the 3rd number which is 1.5
**FORMAT_VALUE:**  Takes the output of VAR_2 which represents the total calculation formatted with a $ in front of the total number with no rounding.

**Sample Code**

```
%%[
SET @VAR_1 = Multiply(365,339.00)
SET @VAR_2 = Multiply(@VAR_1,1.5)
SET @FORMAT_VALUE = Format(@VAR_2,"$#,#")
]%%

%%=v(@FORMAT_VALUE)=%%
```

Comment: Why should the OP try it? Please add some explanation rather than just a code dump. Also, if you select a code block, you can format it by hitting the `{}` button in the editor. Same thing if you hit `CTRL + K` (`⌘ + K` on mac).