# Round a number with AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, rounding

The output for quantity field: `%%=v(@Quantity__c)=%%` is a decimal number (2.0 for example), how can I round this value with AMPscript to be just (2)?

Comment: Take a look at sfdcfox answer on [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57646/how-to-get-the-floor-round-down-instead-of-up-of-a-number-with-ampscript) post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%%=FormatNumber(v(@Quantity__c),"D0","en-US")=%%
```

Third parameter to format number is optional. D0 means decimal with 0 precision.

Comment: i tried  %%=FormatNumber(v(@Quantity__c),"NO","fr-FR")=%% and it worked fine thank you !

Comment: glad to hear it, both have the same end result